# Robotframework, variables within nested keywords

Tags: variables, robotframework

I have some low level keywords where I set variables, I then use those keywords to build second level keywords and with those I build the final level keywords. I would like to populate those variables on the final keywords.
Is there any way I can do that without having to explicitly call my variables again on my second level keywords?
Currently i have to do the following, and it makes the test writing tedious

```
Fill user name
  [Arguments]  ${userName}=name
  input text  //*[@name='name']  ${userName}

Fill user age
  [Arguments]  ${userAge}=age
  input text  //*[@name='age']  ${userAge}

Fill user info
  [Arguments]  ${userName}=name  ${userAge}=age
  Fill user name  ${userName}
  Fill user age  ${userAge}

Fill user info  ${userName}  ${userAge}
```

Preferably I would like to do something like this, is that possible?

```
Fill user name
  [Arguments]  ${userName}=name
  input text  //*[@name='name']  ${userName}

Fill user age
  [Arguments]  ${userAge}=age
  input text  //*[@name='age']  ${userAge}


Fill user info
  Fill user name
  Fill user age

Fill user info  ${userName}  ${userAge}
```

Comment: There is a way you could do it with setting variables at the test level scope, I could show you but to be honest I think it would make it messy and more code. The original way you have it is the way I would do it.

I guess if you have an often repeated user then you could have that users name/age as the default arguments and have keyword "Fill default user info" with no arguments as well as "Fill custom user info" with arguments but that depends on your situation

Comment: thanks @MatthewKing, currently i am using a repeated user, but to extend the tests it would be nice to be able to place other variables, I guess it will just have to be done the long way. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: sure no worries - another option.. depending on your current approach, if you wanted to run the same tests with different users, you could potentially set username and age on command line and have them as global variables, but if they're specific tests for different users then that wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
Fill user name
  [Arguments]  ${userName}=name
  input text  //*[@name='name']  ${userName}

Fill user age
  [Arguments]  ${userAge}=age
  input text  //*[@name='age']  ${userAge}


Fill user info
  [Arguments]  ${userName}=name  ${userAge}=age
  Fill user name  ${userName}
  Fill user age  ${userAge}

Fill user info  ${userName}  ${userAge}
```

Comment: thats already my current set up, but thanks for trying